# Determine whether file is being accessed by another process when using XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xmltextreader

Is there any way to read the file if being used by another process?

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(inpXMLfileAsString);
```

Comment: this heavily depends on how the other process is using the file. could you specify?

Comment: The process using the file would only be a user that has the file open.  I know it's possible with filestream with System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite.  Not sure how to do with XML reader though.

Comment: how about try catching an IOException? If the IOException is thrown, you can identify whether you had access to the file or not.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the [FileStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filestream) in order to open the file in read only mode and pass the stream to the [XmlTextReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4.aspx):

```
var fileStream = new FileStream("c:\\location\\file.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(fileStream);
```

or using directly the [File.OpenRead method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\location\\file.xml"));
```

When the file is opened in read only mode then the other process could still acces the file normally. An example would be to read a log file, while the log file is open for writing and filled by some (other) process.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Depende del modo en el que el otro proceso  abrió el archivo.
For example I opened this way

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(inpXMLfileAsString, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
using (XmlTextWriter reader = new XmlTextWriter(stream,Encoding.UTF8))
{
//Here can write
}
}
```

You can open it in other process using

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(inpXMLfileAsString, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
{
//Here can read
}
}
```

But if the file is open with  `FileShare.None` cant open it in other process